# Yii Setting a custom URL format

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, yii, url-routing

What i am trying to do is to create a custom rule in Yii for URL management.

The general URL rules are set in main.php

```
    'urlManager'=>array(
        'urlFormat'=>'path',
                    'showScriptName'=>false,
        'rules'=>array(
            '<controller:\w+>'=>'<controller>/index',
                            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
        ),
```

the .htaccess file is also set like

```
RewriteEngine on
# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d


# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

so i have URLs in the form

> local/cp/xyz/create

Now i have a custom controller for which the current URL is like

> local/cp/xyz/create/abc

what i want is

> local/cp/abc/create

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming 'local/cp' is your application url, 'xyz' is the controller and 'abc' is some kind of variable (I'll call it `myVar`), you'd need a rule like so:

```
'<myVar:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'xyz/<action>',
```

or

```
'<myVar:\w+>/create'=>'xyz/create',
```

Comment: Sort of.. Actually i got it working. What i had to use was,
'<_mod:(abc|cbd)>/<_ac:(create|delete)>' => 'xyz/<_ac>/<_mod>',

It got hard to explain my question.